# Azure web app access restrictions between Apps

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have 2 app service plans in the same Azure region running 1 app each - web frontend on one, API on the other.

I want to use access restrictions on the API to only allow access from the front end app.

I set access restriction rules using all the outgoing IP addresses associated with the frontend app  (I note that these are exactly the same as the outgoing IP addresses on the API app as well) however when the frontend app tries to contact the API I get an error:

403 forbidden 'The web app you have attempted to reach has blocked your access.'

The 2 apps can communicate as normal when the access restrictions are removed.

Comment: Why don't you implement CORS Policy on your API?

Answer (score 1):

I turned on diagnostic settings and ran a query on IP blocking by the app.

Turns out that the FE app is using an IPv6 address instead of the v4 addresses listed in the app properties.

This is because the app has a vnet integration set up connecting to a Subnet delegated to Webservice/serverfarm.

Azure does not make it obvious that using delegated subnets forces an integrated app to use IPv6 and there does not appear to be a way to discover what v6 addresses may be in use.   MS forum response suggests any firewall rule for a web app attached to a delegated subnet should allow ALL IPv6 addresses (!!) as a way of working around the problem.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/493483/why-is-my-azure-web-app-showing-an-ipv6-outbound-i.html

Answer (score 0):

You can control the IP address of outbound traffic from your FE web app by using regional VNet integration together with a virtual network NAT gateway to direct traffic through a static public IP address. Regional VNet integration is available on **Standard**, **Premium**, **PremiumV2** and **PremiumV3** App Service plans. To learn more about this setup, see [NAT gateway integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet).

Once you FE web app has a static IP you can use that on the API web app restriction in an **ALLOW** rule.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.  

I'm not sure why this is different to allowing traffic from all the IP addresses associated with the app service plan though?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement fits, you may also leverage Service Endpoints.
With service endpoints,to ensure inbound traffic to your API app comes only from the subnet used by your front-end web app.

With this route, you need to use VNet Integration with your front end app and service endpoints with your API app. Set service endpoints on the integration subnet used by your Front End application. This solution is fast to set up and easy as well.

[image: Frontend and backend apps via Service Endpoints]

-This feature works together with IP access restrictions. Service endpoints aren't compatible with remote debugging. There are some considerations you need to make, you may take a look at them [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking-features#create-multitier-applications) and also other combination of networking features available on App Service and related scenarios.

As a side note:

-IP-based access restriction rules only handle virtual network address ranges when your app is in an App Service Environment. If your app is in the multitenant service, you need to use service endpoints to restrict traffic to select subnets in your virtual network.

-On App Service, you could have those two separate apps in the same App Service Plan (ASP), since you pay only for ASP, saving costs.
So, you can continue to add apps to an existing plan as long as the plan has enough resources to handle the load. The apps in the same App Service plan all share the same compute resource.

Comment: Just curious, would the use of API Management and subscription key handle this use case. Without a subscription key, no other app can make calls to the API app. I know this adds to the cost of overall solution.